# Function nested in stored procedure that have parameters in SQL server below but not work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function nested in stored procedure that have parameters in SQL server below but not work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Select_ByStation1] (@Station NVARCHAR (20), @BrqDateStart DATETIME = NULL, @BrqDateEnd   DATETIME = NULL)
RETURNS TABLE
AS

IF ((@BrqDateStart IS NOT NULL)AND(@BrqDateEnd IS NOT NULL))
    BEGIN
     RETURN 
    ( SELECT * FROM dbo.Select_ByStation(@Station)AS TAB    
      WHERE TAB.BrqDate BETWEEN (@BrqDateStart)AND(DATEADD(S,-1, DATEADD(D, 1, @BrqDateEnd))));
    END

    ELSE IF ((@BrqDateStart IS NULL)OR(@BrqDateEnd IS NULL))
    BEGIN

     RETURN 
    ( SELECT * FROM dbo.Select_ByStation(@Station)AS TAB);
    END 
GO
```

and i get this errors

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Select_ByStation1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. Msg 178, Level 15, State 1,
>   Procedure Select_ByStation1, Line 9 A RETURN statement with a return
>   value cannot be used in this context. Msg 178, Level 15, State 1,
>   Procedure Select_ByStation1, Line 17 A RETURN statement with a return
>   value cannot be used in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An in-line table valued function cannot have an `if` . . . just a query.  You could change this to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Select_ByStation1] (@Station NVARCHAR (20), @BrqDateStart DATETIME = NULL, @BrqDateEnd   DATETIME = NULL)
RETURNS @retval TABLE (
    <list columns here>
   )
AS
BEGIN

    IF ((@BrqDateStart IS NOT NULL)AND(@BrqDateEnd IS NOT NULL))
        BEGIN
         insert into retval (. . .)
            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.Select_ByStation(@Station)AS TAB    
            WHERE TAB.BrqDate BETWEEN (@BrqDateStart)AND(DATEADD(S,-1, DATEADD(D, 1, @BrqDateEnd))));
        END

    ELSE IF ((@BrqDateStart IS NULL)OR(@BrqDateEnd IS NULL))
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @retval (. . .)
                SELECT *
                FROM dbo.Select_ByStation(@Station)AS TAB;
        END ;
    RETURN ;
END;
```

Note:  This assumes that the two queries return the same table structure.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff, the your answer give this error "Msg 455, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Select_ByStation1, Line 28
The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.'

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL function and get rid of the IF which checks whether the arguments are null or not. Something like this:

```
RETURN ( 
   SELECT * FROM dbo.Select_ByStation(@Station) AS TAB    
   WHERE TAB.BrqDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@BrqDateStart,'19000101') AND 
   DATEADD(S,-1, DATEADD(D, 1, ISNULL(@BrqDateEnd,'20500101'))))
```